# How is the direction of the hydraulic fluid changed so that the cylinders and pistons can move backwards and forwards?

Tags: aircraft-performance, fluid-mechanics, hydraulic-system

How is the direction of the hydraulic fluid changed, so that components and actuators (cylinders and pistons) can move backwards and forwards?

Comment: Aircraft use hydraulic systems, but not really sure this is aircraft related.

Comment: This is really a very basic mechanical engineering question.

Comment: Using hydraulic valves.

Comment: Take a look at [How Do Hydraulic Cylinders Work?](https://www.hydrauliconline.com/hydraulic-cylinders/how-do-hydraulic-cylinders-work/)

Comment: The fluid direction does not change, there is a valve that either directs fluid to the extension side of the piston, or the retraction side of the piston. The "non-pressure" side of the piston is also directed back to the tank so that there isn't (much) back-pressure on the other side of the piston.

Comment: I agree the question is not aviation specific but I would argue to keep the question here as I don't know if there is some specififcity for aircraft's hydraulic systems (perhaps speed or reliability constraints)

Answer (score 4):

The direction of travel is controlled by a directional control valve for a double acting cylinder.

[image]

The red line is high pressure from hydraulic pump. when the high pressure fluid is entering the right chamber and push the actuator piston to left.
The low pressure fluid in left chamber (blue line) will leave the actuator and return to reservoir.

If we rotated/move the directional control valve clockwise it will look like the figure below :

[image]

The high pressure will enter the left chamber and move the actuator piston to right

Comment: Downvoted as it clearly need editing efforts before reaching quality standard as defined in the help center

Comment: @ManuH got edited, see if you want to rethink your vote

Comment: I agree ilustration improve the answer's quality, but it still lack editing efforts. e.g. the first sentence is not a sentence.

Comment: @ManuH Then edit it?

Comment: Great diagrams!